# NSPopUpButton Grayed Out in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, macos, swift-playground, appkit

In the Swift playground view controller I have the following code:

```swift
var jsonSelector = NSPopUpButton(title: "Path", target: self, action: #selector(updatePointFile))

override public func loadView() {
    let frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 900, height: 600))
    let view = NSView(frame: frame)

    let array = // gets array of items
    for item in array {
        jsonSelector.addItem(withTitle: item)
    }

    view.addSubview(jsonSelector)
    self.view = view
}

@objc func updatePointFile() {
    let file = jsonSelector.selectedItem?.title ?? "swiftLogo"
    ...
}
```

When it runs it initially looks normal:
[image: normal]

But then once it is clicked it looks like:
[image: broken]

And when you click away it stays unclickable:
[image: still broken]

When I copy the exact same code into a full mac app it works like normal, and to make things even weirder, one time when I was taking those screenshots it worked for once selection and returned to it's grayed out state.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to this is kinda weird. It just requires defining the target later.

That means either

```swift
var jsonSelector = NSPopUpButton(frame: NSRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)))

override public func loadView() {
    jsonSelector.target = self
        jsonSelector.action = #selector(updatePointFile)

    let array = // gets array of items
    for item in array {
        jsonSelector.addItem(withTitle: item)
    }

    view.addSubview(jsonSelector)
    self.view = view
}

@objc func updatePointFile() {
    let file = jsonSelector.selectedItem?.title ?? "swiftLogo"
    ...
}
```

or

```swift
var jsonSelector = NSPopUpButton(title: "Path", target: self, action: #selector(updatePointFile))

override public func loadView() {
    let frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 900, height: 600))
    let view = NSView(frame: frame)

    jsonSelector.target = self

    let array = // gets array of items
    for item in array {
        jsonSelector.addItem(withTitle: item)
    }

    view.addSubview(jsonSelector)
    self.view = view
}

@objc func updatePointFile() {
    let file = jsonSelector.selectedItem?.title ?? "swiftLogo"
    ...
}
```

works

Comment: Was the solution switching the statements or adding `jsonSelector.target = self`?

Comment: Willeke, you're right. `jsonSelector.target = self` is enough to fix it. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Changing the order of assigning a target and action also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue here but within an Objective-C project within an NSViewController.

**It is related to the First Responder chain.**

I could resolve it with this call:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    [super viewDidAppear];

    [self.view.window makeFirstResponder: self];
}
```